# Is it possible to use requirejs inside html script tag?

Tags: javascript, requirejs

Is there a way to require a file inside of a script tag? I currently have the following.

index.html:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script data-main="data" src="../../common/static/require.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script>
      define(function (require) {
        var result = require('./main.js');
        console.log(result)
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

main.js:

```
define(function () {
  return {
    foo: 'bar'
  };
});
```

But I am currently getting this error in my browser: `Uncaught Error: Mismatched anonymous define() module`. I have read [this](http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#mismatch) but I still don't understand what the solution is.

Comment: it's obvious tho. _To avoid the error: Be sure to load all scripts that call define() via the RequireJS API. Do not manually code script tags in HTML to load scripts that have define() calls in them_ ....from link you provided

Comment: "Be sure to load all scripts that call define() via the RequireJS API." I just don't understand how to do this. Sorry, I know it's obvious, I'm just not getting it.

Comment: `require` requires a file with `define`, in order to define a module that needs to be required. So put the code inside the script Tag in a file, and use `require` to require it. Second, always set the 3 arguments for CommonJS style, `require, exports, module`.